# Kafka JDBC source connector

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka

I'm trying the JDBC source connector to get data from SQL Server.

I'm getting the error saying

> ERROR Failed to create job for etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-quickstart-sqlserver.properties

My properties file look like below. What am I missing?

```
name=test-sqlserver-jdbc-autoincrement
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://******:1433;databaseName=****;user=****l;password=****
table.whitelist=****
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=id
topic.prefix=test-sqlserver-jdbc-
```

Also if I try to get the error details using `curl http://localhost:8083 /JdbcSourceConnector/config/validate`, I get error url malformed which I believe is a bug in kafka 10.2.0

Comment: Are you trying to run this connector in standalone mode or as a distributed connector? For distributed mode the config file you post (or validate) with curl commands needs to be in the proper JSON format.

Comment: standalone mode

Comment: There is an example QuickStart for standalone mode jdbc source Connector on Confluent website. See http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_connector.html

Comment: thx ! i followed it but still getting the error

Answer (score 1):

if you are on an experimental environment try the following.

```
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/my_db
connection.user=user
connection.password=pass
useSSL=false
```

also make sure that the incrementing column name is correct and that it is `auto-increment`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below properties file.

```
name=test-mysql-jdbc-autoincrement
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/training?user=admin&password=password@538&useSSL=false

query=select emp.emp_dept_id, emp.timestamp, emp.emp_name, dept.dept_name from kafka_employee emp join kafka_department dept on emp.emp_dept_id = dept.dept_id
mode=timestamp+incrementing

incrementing.column.name=emp_dept_id
timestamp.column.name=timestamp

topic.prefix=test-mysql-jdbc-kp
poll.interval.ms = 1000
```