# Connect kafka to jdbc database

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

Can someone show me how to connect my kafka server to a jdbc postgresql database and retrieve data from it  ? all the tutorials on the internet got me more confused !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kafka JDBC source connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43958091/kafka-jdbc-source-connector)

Answer (score 1):

You've not said which tutorials you've tried, or in what way you got confused…but the short answer is to use the [Kafka Connect JDBC Connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/).

You can find examples [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_connector.html#quick-start) and [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/).

Another option to explore is another Kafka Connect connector, called [Debezium](http://debezium.io/). This implements proper Change-Data-Capture (CDC) against Postgres.